# How can I display all levels in Simple hierarchical select

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I created select hierarchy ( taxonomy with 3 level), but in default it shows only one level , how can I display all 3 level in default page? : -Any- + -Any- + -Any-

I do not want it to automatically generate other fields.I want to display by default all the select input

[image]

Comment: I am looking for the same Question's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the answer was to create a custom module and not use SHS. Here's how I did it with Drupal 8 ... and some info on how done with D7: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/269296/18513

Comment: This is another alternative (still in sandbox) https://github.com/bmcclure/drupal-views_selective_filters

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 you will need to use the "[business rules](https://themerevel.com/tutorials/how-to-add-hierarchical-select-form-in-drupal-8/)" module to add hierarchical select...